# how to know if your number is blocked?

Tags: iphone

so i know when your number is blocked it will not say delivered when sent through imessage and when sent as a text message you’ll get a notification that says it could not be delivered. what if it doesn’t send through but also doesn’t say not delivered? are you still blocked?